# Compute different dataframes using a foor loop based on df.columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a date column and 10 other columns with values. Now I want to have 10 dataframes where each dataframe has the date column and one of the other columns.

What I tried is this:

```
for i in df.columns:
    i = df[["Datum", i]]
    print(i)
```

df.columns looks like this:

```
In [29]: df.columns
Out[29]: Index(['Datum', 'Alle', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'M', 'P', 'V', 'X'], dtype='object')
```

The result I get looks like this and is what I want:

```
        Datum      Datum
0  2019-01-31 2019-01-31
1  2019-02-28 2019-02-28
2  2019-03-28 2019-03-28
3  2019-04-30 2019-04-30
4  2019-05-29 2019-05-29
5  2019-06-28 2019-06-28
6  2019-07-31 2019-07-31
7  2019-08-30 2019-08-30
8  2019-09-30 2019-09-30
9  2019-10-31 2019-10-31
10 2019-11-29 2019-11-29
11 2019-12-31 2019-12-31
        Datum       Alle
0  2019-01-31   3.667723
1  2019-02-28   8.701268
2  2019-03-28  14.552034
3  2019-04-30  19.510565
4  2019-05-29  25.989171
5  2019-06-28  34.508452
6  2019-07-31  39.776545
7  2019-08-30  46.492076
8  2019-09-30  52.749604
9  2019-10-31  59.086107
10 2019-11-29  70.755943
11 2019-12-31  96.143687
        Datum          B
0  2019-01-31   2.655556
1  2019-02-28   6.244444
2  2019-03-28  12.033333
3  2019-04-30  16.133333
4  2019-05-29  19.577778
5  2019-06-28  24.666667
6  2019-07-31  28.455556
7  2019-08-30  31.077778
8  2019-09-30  36.433333
9  2019-10-31  40.088889
10 2019-11-29  47.055556
11 2019-12-31  98.888889
```

(..... The Output goes on for all columns)

However if I want to see one of the dataframes or type into my console:

```
Alle.info()
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Alle' is not defined
```

So apparently the dataframes are computed correctly but I can't use them as I thought I could. Does anybody know how to save these dataframes with different names? Preferably with the column name they contain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
dfs = {col : df[['Datum', col]] for col in df.columns[1:]}

dfs['Alle'].info()
```